# Why and when we should use argument.length in ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Below code is taken from [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/). But I do not understand, why at the time that the author use fullName as computed property, he did the check for setter with `arguments.length` instead of `value.length`, which may more related to the `value` variable that is assigned to the function. I **wonder what is the difference and why he is using arguments.length in this case**?

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function(key, value) {
    // setter
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      var nameParts = value.split(/\s+/);
      this.set('firstName', nameParts[0]);
      this.set('lastName',  nameParts[1]);
    }

    // getter
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});


var captainAmerica = App.Person.create();
captainAmerica.set('fullName', "William Burnside");
captainAmerica.get('firstName'); // William
captainAmerica.get('lastName'); // Burnside
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: @SLaks, thanks! I concluded after reading, that, its arguments because it represent an array that can allow multiple values, so that its more dynamic and scalable then using value, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if clause makes sure that the value has been passed by the caller.

Checking the length of the `arguments` is the correct way to do that, even though you might encounter things like `if (value)` or `if (value !== undefined)` or something similar in less careful code. Checking `arguments.length` distinguishes between the function called with only one argument (as a getter) and with two arguments (as a setter) with the second argument being `undefined`.

Comment: so the 1 is actually the AMOUNT of arguments right? and arguments.length is like counting the number of objects for the arugments array?

Comment: Exactly. `arguments.length` is read as "the number of elements in the array-like structure `arguments`". `arguments` is a special structure populated with the values you called the function with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments